# what the difference between n*fun(n-1) and fun(n-1)*n

Tags: recursion

I want to write function implement n! like this:

```
int fun(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return n * fun(n-1);
}
```

I want to know that what the difference between `n * fun(n-1)` and `fun(n-1)*n`. which one is better?

Comment: `n*returnValue` or `returnValue*n`? Looks equal to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is right-recursive and one is left-recursive, otherwise, they are equivalent.

Lets watch how the stack builds in each case for fact(3).

fact(n) = n*fact(n-1)

```
(n * ((n-1) * ((n-2) * ...)))  <-- notice stack depth
(3  * (2 * (1)))
 3 * 2 * 1
 6
```

fact(n) = fact(n-1)*n

```
(((... * (n-2)) * (n-1)) * n)  <-- stack depth the same, but factors in reverse
(((1) * 2) * 3)
 1 * 2 * 3
 6
```

EDIT: Response to your followup regarding stack space.

No, the same stack space is used, see above where I show it. Now you can do away with the stack space if you rewrite as a tail-call.

The original forms both have in common the fact that they cannot be tail-call optimized because of the multiplication factor that must be pushed on the stack to be evaluated once the leaf call returns. Rewriting with an accumulator would solve that.

Something like this, for example. fact(n) can call fact_tailcall(n,accum) which simply uses an accumulator variable to avoid saving the evaluation context with each recursive call.

```
fact(n) {
   return fact_tailcall(n,1)
}

fact_tailcall(n,accum) {
   if(n == 1)
      return 1
   accum = n * accum
   return fact_tailcall(n-1,accum)
}

(3)
(3,1) <-- Or you can just call fact_tailcall directly with (n, 1)
(2,3)
(1,6) <-- stack never really grows
6
```

In the latter, no additional computations follow the recursive call, so the compiler can optimize away the whole stack of recursive calls into a single call and convert to an "iteration". The compiler skips all of the intermediate recursion by reusing the stack space for the arguments rather than saving each frame. "n" may occupy a single register, as will "accum". The function doesn't have to back out of nested calls, instead it just returns directly with a "goto" at the end. Passing along the work (accum) is the essence of continuation passing style in functional programming.

Comment: Hi codenheim, thanks for your reply. I know that the result is same. However, from the stack space view, is there any different ? wether the fun(n-1)*n can save the stack space ?

Comment: Stack space is the same for your versions, but you can rewrite with an accumulator to allow tail call optimization. Let me edit my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

No difference either way. The fun function has to calculate what n - 1 is before it can multiply the current n. It's like saying 2(3)+4 vs. 4+2(3) either way you have to multiply before you can add.

Comment: Hi Linsanity, thanks for your reply. I know that the result is same. However, from the stack space view, is there any different ? wether the fun(n-1)*n can save the stack space ?